# Assigning ascii values in mips

Tags: ascii, mips

I am a bit new to mips and am trying to set a .asciiz variable equal to another, then print it. This is what I have:

```
.data
s: .asciiz "I never could get the hang of Thursdays."
s2: .space 50
.text
main:
la $t0, s
la $t1, s2
lbu $t2, 0($t0)
sb $t2, 0($t1)

la $a0, s2
li $v0, 4
syscall

li   $v0, 10
syscall
```

However, I am only able to print one byte at a time. How can I print the whole string?

Comment: Do you have an instruction-set reference for MIPS? Have you had a look at the branch-instructions?

Comment: Now I have, thanks. Is there a way to set a variable to a full ascii string without branching (i.e., just using lw/sw instructions)?

Comment: You could unroll the loop (have a `lb/sb`-pair for every character in the string), provided you know the length of the string in advance. That's not particularly flexible though.

Comment: I see. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.